# Generate random balls shoot towards circle?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Well i have a circle on the screen of my game which is centred and i want to shoot balls towards it. I am able to spawn balls, but i don't have a clue on how to give them random positions and apply impulse to them, so that they shoot towards the ball.

Comment: What have you done so far to try and solve this problem?

Comment: Well i tried to create a vector that shoots the ball towards the vector, however the ball was created in the middle of the scene and fired the vector in opposite direction